# vscode - How to auto-enable regex when searching?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have regex search enabled by default. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You start search with CTRL+H and then you switch to Regex search with ALT+R or you click option in search window on the right side of the popup.

Comment: And vscode will remember whatever it was set to last time you closed the find widget.  Only problem is with the Find in All Files option: Ctrl-Shift-H if it isn't already set to regex and there is a value already in the find field, then focus is set to the replace field and alt-R won't set to regex.  Hitting Shift-tab will move focus back to the find field and then alt-R will work.